# Tcl/Tk: scope of variables for a function within a function

Tags: scope, tcl, upvar

I'm getting lost on scoping variables in Tcl.  I've got two procs I've written and stored in a file that I want to call in another script I'm writing.  In my sourced file (which I'll call `bar.tcl`), I'm using `upvar` to define a bunch of variables at the beginning of my file that I plan to call within the procs I've defined within `bar.tcl`, which I'll call `bar1` and `bar2`

I want to call the functions within `bar.tcl` from my code within `foo.tcl`.  My functions work fine if I'm just interacting with bar.tcl in tclsh, but as soon as I call bar1 or bar2 from within a function in foo.tcl, I get an error `can't read "alpha": no such variable`

It seems I'm using `upvar` incorrectlys.  Is this even the right tool for the job?  What can I do so that I can achieve the following?

1. define a bunch of variables at the beginning of `bar.tcl` that I want to use in both procs `bar1` and `bar2,` and
2. call `bar1` and `bar2` from within procs defined in `foo.tcl`

Here's my code in `foo.tcl`:

```
# foo.tcl
source bar.tcl

proc foo {fooValues} {
    foreach fooValue $fooValues {
        set myNewValue [bar1 $fooValue]
        return $myNewValue
    }
}

set myOldValues {5 10 15 20 25}
foo myOldValues
```

And here's my code in `bar.tcl`:

```
set a apples
set b bananas
set c cherries
set d dates

proc bar1 {bar} {
    upvar a alpha
    upvar b bravo
    upvar c charlie
    upvar d delta

    set myReturnValue "$bar $alpha $bravo $charlie $delta"
    return $myReturnValue
}

proc bar2 {bar} {
    upvar a alpha
    upvar b bravo
    upvar c charlie
    upvar d delta

    set myReturnValue "$alpha $bravo $charlie $delta $bar"
    return $myReturnValue
}
```

Comment: Your `return` lines throughout `foo.tcl` and `bar.tcl` should provide for variable substitution. Right now, they return literally the variable names. Write `$myReturnValue` instead of `myReturnValue` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `bar1`, `bar2`, ... are called from within `foo`, their `upvar` calls will try to link with any proc-local variables of the executed `foo` proc. This is because [`upvar`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm) without level defaults to `upvar 1` which denotes the proc's caller (i.e., `foo`). Your targeted variables in `bar.tcl`, however, reside in the global namespace and not within `foo`. Hence, there are no variables linked by `alpha`, `bravo`.

Rewrite your `upvar` occurrences as `upvar #0 ...`, with `#0` indicating the global, top-level namespace, e.g.:

```
upvar "#0" a alpha
```

This is equivalent to using `global a` modulo a variable alias (`alpha`).

Comment: You may omit the double-quotes in `"#0"`, they are only needed here to trick the syntax highlighter.

Comment: So, tangential question, how do the variables outside the scope of the `bar` procs (`a b c d`) ever get set?  Does that happen when i source `bar.tcl`?  In other words, how do I/am I actually making those variables global with the code above, or is there an additional bit of info I need to include?

Comment: Yes, when you source `bar.tcl` (as shown above), they are created in the top-level (global) namespace.